# Dynamically added control missing in live visual tree

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Dynamically added control missing in live visual tree (Visual Basic 2019). How can I update this tree so I could inspect control's properties?

[image: screen]

Comment: Are you sure the added controls aren't elsewhere in the tree? Otherwise you should file a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: I checked the all tree- they are gone.. 


it's strange because dynamically added tabitem appears

Comment: In the toolbox (middle top small bar on the wpf app) check all, then you will be able to click on control and it will automatically be highlighted in visual tree. This way you will find them. Most probably they just aren't where you expect them to be :)

Comment: yes, I have tried this, but these controls can't be selected :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a icon named `Show Just My Xaml` in the `Live Visual Tree` like below picture shown:
[image]

When you click it , you will see all the control in the tree.**Show Just My XAML** icon on the toolbar is starting in **Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4**, the view of XAML elements is simplified by default using the Just My XAML feature.

Here is the picture which I click it:
[image]

Comment: If the answer is what you are looking for, could you accept it as answer which can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.